# How to trace or diagnose Angular 2's dependency injection miss-behavior?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am building Angular2 unit tests using Jasmine.

I am using TestBed.get to get an instance of a Typescript object.

For one of the service classes, TestBed.get returns a wrong instance of an object and I am not able to find why.

Is there any online article, DI diagnosis technique, debugging technique, or tracing capability that explains why Angular injector (TestBed.get) decides to create a wrong unexpected instance of the service class?

Is there any way to dump the actual provider list that angular finds service class based upon?

**Update 1: Adding clarification based on @estus comments:**

Please note that I am not looking for finding what is wrong with a specific code, so someone spots a mistake in my code. I am looking for a technique and a systematic way to find how exactly injector is configured at runtime.

Also, is it possible to use Augury in Jasmine's browser environment?

Comment: The question is pointless without actual code that shows what's wrong. You can debug the injector with Chrome's Augury for example.

Comment: @estus, I am very familiar with Augury but I don't know if it works in Jasmine's browser environment.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @estus, I added clarification to my question.

Comment: Augury can be used to trace the problem in regular app, if it originates from there. It doesn't look like it works in TestBed environment because it relies on `@angular/platform-browser/browser/testability` which isn't initialized in TestBed (probably there's a trick to enable it there). The injector can be debugged from console with `ng.probe`, which is likely used by Augury too. The point of a remark on specific code is that such problems often originate from improper testing methodology. Efficient unit tests are very isolated and easy to diagnose.

Comment: @estus, I appreciate your help here. I agree with your comments in regards to the code. At the same time, it is a legitimate expectation to be able to trace Dependency Injection activities. Most DI frameworks provide that. I am surprised how come it is missing from Angular's TestBed (Angular Jasmine integration).

Comment: I've added the answer. It doesn't address DI in whole but is limited to how this can be sorted out in hierarchical injectors in components, if this was your case. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging information is available on [component fixtures](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/ComponentFixture) in `TestBed`:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
```

When a reference to it was stored, [debug element](https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement) can be retrieved with:

```
console.log(fixture.debugElement);
```

If it weren't stored, debug elements can be retrieved from current test bed:

```
console.log(getTestBed()._activeFixtures.map(fixture => fixture.debugElement));
```

This piece of code

```
class Svc {
  name = 'foo';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'comp',
  providers: [Svc],
  template: ``,
})
class Comp {
  constructor(public svc: Svc) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<comp></comp>`,
})
class App {
  constructor(public svc: Svc) {}
}
```

and this test bed:

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [App, Comp],
    providers:  [{ provide: Svc, useValue: { name: 'bar' } }]
  })
```

will result in following debug element hierarchy:

[image: debug element]

`svc` instances are available in `context`, and direct child debug element is available in `children`.

Alternatively, debug element can be retrieved from existing DOM element with `ng.probe` global:

```
ng.probe(nativeElement);
```